How should a single page clear the loading GLTFLoader? It will crash the page
When page a uses GLTFLoader to load glb (24mb), quickly switch to page b. At this time GLTFLoader is still loading, and then I switch back and forth 2-3 times, and it will crash on the mobile terminal.
I tried to use a singleton to cache the return value of GLTFLoader so that it would not call GLTFLoader every time, but it would still crash.


class Character extends EventEmitter {
  loadingManager = null
  loader = null
  model = null
  clock = new THREE.Clock()
  init() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.loadingManager = new THREE.LoadingManager()
      this.loadingManager.onError = error => {
        reject(error)
      }
      this.loader = new GLTFLoader(this.loadingManager)
      this.loader.load(
        `${import.meta.env.VITE_FILE_PATH}/character.glb`,
        gltf => {
          this.model = gltf.scene
          this.model.traverse(o => {
            if (o.isMesh) {
              o.castShadow = true
              o.receiveShadow = true
            }
          })
          resolve()
        },
        ({ loaded, total }) => {
          this.emit('progress', loaded / total)
        },
      )
    })
  }

  unload() {
    this.model?.traverse(obj => {
      if (obj.material) {
        obj.material.dispose()
        if (obj.material.map) {
          obj.material.map.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.lightMap) {
          obj.material.lightMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.aoMap) {
          obj.material.aoMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.emissiveMap) {
          obj.material.emissiveMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.bumpMap) {
          obj.material.bumpMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.normalMap) {
          obj.material.normalMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.displacementMap) {
          obj.material.displacementMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.roughnessMap) {
          obj.material.roughnessMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.metalnessMap) {
          obj.material.metalnessMap.dispose()
        }
        if (obj.material.alphaMap) {
          obj.material.alphaMap.dispose()
        }
      }
      if (obj.geometry) {
        obj.geometry.dispose()
      }
    })
    return this
  }
}




I tried to use a singleton perhaps you did it wrong, or doing something else wrong in your absent code - how are you using both reactjs and vuejs on the same page though? are you actually doing that? or are you using neither?

@JaromandaX Hello, I am giving an example. The tag is just to attract people with relevant experience. My project uses vue. I am wondering whether I should use keep-alive to cache this page. I just reduced the model to 15mb, but the problem is the same, it just crashes after switching 3-4 times.

If your project doesn't use reactjs, then don't tag the question with reactjs - tag spamming is not encouraged - and you still haven't shown anything you've actually done, just a vague description. How can anyone help if you don't show what you have done

You cant use keepalive to cathe a model,if you really want to cache it,moving it to root component(app.vue) and setting  z-index = -1 to hide it,when swich  to pageA  set the z-index =1 to show it

@JaromandaX Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I have adapted and added the code, there are methods for loading and for unloading. This code is called on page a. Frequent switching of pages a and b will cause a crash.

@moon I'm wondering if it can also be avoided by THREE.Cache.clear()
